# How to fix element type is invalid expected a string or a class/function error in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm creating a music app using react native and I install "react-native-slider" "react-native-video" packages. When I run the application it gives an error "element type is invalid expected a string or a class/function(for composite component) but got: object". How can I fix this problem?

[image: This is the error I got.]

**This is my SeekBar.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
    
var Slider = require('react-native-slider');
    
function pad(n, width, z=0) {
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}
    
const minutesAndSeconds = (position) => ([
  pad(Math.floor(position / 60), 2),
  pad(position % 60, 2),
]);
    
const SeekBar = ({
  trackLength,
  currentPosition,
  onSeek,
  onSlidingStart,
}) => {
  const elapsed = minutesAndSeconds(currentPosition);
  const remaining = minutesAndSeconds(trackLength - currentPosition);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          {elapsed[0] + ":" + elapsed[1]}
        </Text>
        <View style={{flex: 1}} />
        <Text style={[styles.text, {width: 40}]}>
          {trackLength > 1 && "-" + remaining[0] + ":" + remaining[1]}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <Slider
        maximumValue={Math.max(trackLength, 1, currentPosition + 1)}
        onSlidingStart={onSlidingStart}
        onSlidingComplete={onSeek}
        value={currentPosition}
        style={styles.slider}
        minimumTrackTintColor='#fff'
        maximumTrackTintColor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14)'
        thumbStyle={styles.thumb}
        trackStyle={styles.track}/>
    </View>
  );
};
    
export default SeekBar;
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  slider: {
    marginTop: -12,
  },
  container: {
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,
    paddingTop: 16,
  },
  track: {
    height: 2,
    borderRadius: 1,
  },
  thumb: {
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72)',
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign:'center',
  }
});
```

Comment: Place `export defaut SeekBar` at the end of the file

Comment: What is line 32 in the file?

Comment: I already add it in the end of the file

Comment: <View style={styles.container}> this code line is in 32

Comment: Are there any way to convert the function into Class declarations?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @react-native-community/slider --save
npx pod-install
react-native run-ios
```

Change code as follows:

```js
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
    
<Slider 
    style={{width: 200, height: 40}}
    minimumValue={0}
    maximumValue={1}
    minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
    maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
    />
```

It works for me with the above.